# Why does StorageFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions return no files when the user picks a user library folder?

Tags: uwp

In a UWP I'm writing I am prompting the user for a folder using the FolderPicker class, then calling CreateFileQueryWithOptions on the resulting StorageFolder object to get a list of files.  This works great with most folders, but if the user chooses a user library folder, like Downloads or Pictures or (sometimes) Documents, the resulting file query doesn't contain any files even though I know that files exist that match the query.  Why is this?  Is there something I need to do in code to make this work, or is it a permission my app has to declare?

Comment: How are you constructing your query?

I've done a little test and don't appear to have any difficulty gettings files normally

Comment: As an addition, there should be no additional permissions that your app should need in order to get files from anywhere on your device.

Comment: Played around with this some more and have some more observations.  When I do the query with CommonFileQuery.OrderByName in the QueryOptions, then I get nothing back.  If I use CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery instead, then I do see the files (but not the files in subfolders, as expected).  Also, I tested this on a different computer and didn't see the problem, which furthers the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue too late, but I did some research on it, I tried loading files from my desktop and put a non-indexed folder in there and was not able to get the files from that folder.

The cause might be that the default value of IndexerOption property from QueryOptions is IndexerOption.UseIndexWhenAvailable.

I tried changing that property to IndexerOption.DoNotUseIndexer and was able to get all the files from my desktop including the non-indexed folder.